# Failure authenticating with NTLM <any realm> in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

While Replaying my Jmeter script I am getting the above NTLM and negotiate Authentication kind of errors. Help me to resolve the issue

I have used Authentication Manager . there I have entered my domain and realm details

Please confirm in Authentication manager , I need to give my server name in REALM configuration.

Please share sample krb5.conf details. in the conf file I need to give server details or client details.

Answer (score 0):

No one will be able to help you unless you provide your [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) and [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) configuration.

No one will be able to provide `krb5.conf` and `jaas.conf` files as there are to many ways of configuring Kerberos so client configuration will be very different.

I would suggest getting familiarized with [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) article and if you will be still experiencing problems enable some extra logging by setting the following properties:

- JMeter Property:

  ```
   log_level.org.apache.commons.httpclient.Authenticator=trace
  ```
- Java System Property:

  ```
  sun.security.krb5.debug
  ```

Also you can add `debug=true` line to the **jaas.conf** file

Comment: After Modifying the Authentication manager , I am getting the below           Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2016-11-29 16:17:07 IST
Load time: 1052
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 1052
Size in bytes: 188
Headers size in bytes: 188
Body size in bytes: 0
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): 
Response code: 401
Response message: Unauthorized

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 29 Nov 2016 10:47:07 GMT
Content-Length: 0